# Why wasn't \fbox defined to enclose its contents based on the most left, right, bottom, top parts of its contents? 

Tags: boxes, bounding-box

### Case 1: `\fbox` cannot enclose characters tightly

Why don't `\fbox` and PSTricks `\psframebox` enclose its contents accurately? In my opinion, every edge should exactly touch the outer part of its contents.  Does changing font solve this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=0.001pt

\begin{document}
\color{red}\fbox{\color{black}3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This funny feature might be the source of problem where [pdfcrop accidently trims grid labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20616/2099).

### Case 2: `\fbox` cannot enclose PSTricks grid labels

It is another example where `\fbox` and `\psframebox` cannot accurately enclose their contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\fboxsep=0pt
\fboxrule=0.001pt

\begin{document}

\color{red}
\fbox{\color{black}%
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\endpspicture
}

\vspace{1cm}

\psframebox[framesep=0pt,linewidth=0.001pt,linecolor=red]{%
\pspicture[showgrid](3,3)
\endpspicture
}
\end{document}
```

Should the frames enclose the grid labels? In my mental model, they should.

[image]

### Questions

In my mental model, `\fbox` should enclose its contents tightly when `\fboxsep=0pt` without allowing any part of its contents to reside outside its frame.
If `\fbox` allows any part of its contents to live outside its frame, what is `\fbox` actually for?

*Why wasn't `\fbox` defined to enclose its contents based on the most left, right, bottom, top parts? I think it is more useful, right?*

Comment: In computer modern, all lining figures are exactly half an em wide. I'm not sure why the height and depth are off (and I think the depth should be zero).

Comment: And by off I meant different from the actual characters' heights and depths, not incorrect. Herbert gives a good example.

Comment: `\fbox` is a frame around boxes, not a frame around characters

Comment: @Herbert: Why wasn't `\fbox` defined to enclose its contents based on the most left, right, bottom, top parts?

Comment: I think `\fbox` is considered to be more of a decorative box than you hope.  After all, it has the tuning parameter `\fboxsep` indicating how far from the "real" box the frame should be drawn, and by default, it is not zero.

Comment: @xport: The answer to your question is *because it can't* and Herbert's and mine answers should already have told you this.

Comment: @egreg: Please say that in your answer or Herbert's, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @egrag: Also explain the reason why it cannot do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the bounding box of the character has nothing to do with its contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{3cm}{3.1cm}\selectfont\frame{\itshape ff}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Herbert: If `\fbox` cannot enclose its contents accurately, what is `\fbox` actually for?

Comment: @xport I have used fbox (and the "boxit" macro from the TeXbook) many times to see how much space a box really occupies. I use a similar (LuaTeX node based) approach daily now. But I do agree that a \contentsbox macro could be helpful, too.

Comment: @Patrick: Where is `\contentsbox` defined?

Comment: @xport: Remember that TeX works with boxes and not with characters. For TeX it is aboslutely unimportant what's inside the box, the reason why you can write english and arabic in the same file. The characters are inserted by the driver, not by TeX. For a good typographical reason, the characters e, o, 3, 6, and so on are at the bottom a little bit outside the box.

Comment: @xport, @Herbert: I think it is more instructive to note that TeX typesets words by putting the character boxes together so that they just touch. The character boxes are defined so that the resulting words look “right”. (Exception: Sometimes, this algorithm does not produce acceptable interletter spacing. The font will have kerning tables to deal with those special cases.)

Comment: @xport: There is no such `\contentsbox` macro. Patrick was saying that it would be useful if it _did_ exist.

Comment: @xport: see TH's answer. It doesn't exist, and I am not sure that it can be done easily.

Answer (score 6):

TeX has no notion of how the ink will be used to draw a character. All it knows are the bounding boxes of characters, but typically a glyph is not entirely contained in the bounding box reserved for it. Letters with rounded shape at the top or at the bottom (the digit 3 is a prominent example) usually are drawn slighly over or under the bounding box, to align optically with one another. Often the "f", especially the italic shape, protrudes from its bounding box. It's ***impossible*** for TeX to know whether this happens or not.

However it's possible to access at the "real" bounding box of a character with XeTeX, as shown in [The XeTeX reference guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/xetexref/xetex-reference.pdf), page 8. With TeX Live one can access to the document by `texdoc xetex`.